# When does set_caps of a source element get called?

Tags: linux, fedora, gstreamer

I am writing a `gstreamer` source element. For that, I have looked into sources like v4l2src which are similar to what I need. After going through, this I wonder about the `set_caps` function in it as to when does this function get called ? I know that `set_caps` get called whenver upstream element does a `gst_pad_set_caps`, but who will do this call for a source element which doesn't have a `sinkpad`.

I am interested in this because in v4l2src, stream parameters like width, height and framerate are fetched from this `set_caps` function. So I want to know where are these values getting set ?

Please respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I'm assuming you're using gstreamer 0.10. *gstreamer 0.10 isn't developed anymore, please consider moving to 1.0*

Ok, now to the answer: caps aren't associated with elements, caps are set into pads. So it isn't called for the source element or any element whatsoever. What happens is that it is set to an element's pad. Elements that have a sinkpad (or more than one), will have this caps set from upstream element's buffer's media type. When a buffer flows through a pad, the pad checks the buffer caps and sets it to the pad if it is a new caps. In this case, the set_caps callback of the pad is called. It can also happen that elements explicitly call gst_pad_set_caps on its pads before pushing the buffers, either way is correct.

The usual way is that elements receive some caps on its sink pad (from the media that is produced upstream) and then they do some transformation/decision on what they should produce for downstream and put that on its buffers or set on its source pads. When they push their buffers, this caps will be set on its source pad and on downstream element's sink pad. This way, each pad on each element gets its 'set_caps' called and elements know about the media type that they are handling and decide on what to produce and how to configure themselves.

Source elements are at the top of the pipeline, they inject data on the pipeline and have no sink pads. So they check what downstream can handle using get_caps calls and they can decide on what media to produce on its startup (ready to paused state change). When they decide on caps, the caps is set on buffers/pads and set_caps is called (for their source pads and the next element's sink pad).

Check v4l2src and its base class (basesrc) to understand how this 'caps negotiation' works. IIRC it should be handled from some 'start' function callback. Refer to https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer-libs/0.10/GstBaseSrc.html‎ for understanding how a BaseSrc works and the gstreamer manual (0.10 for your case) for reading about 'caps negotiation'.